# How to Ignore Case

Tags: java, string, while-loop, char, indexof

I have this code here that reads a string and a character, and then finds all the occurrences of that character in that string. But, it only finds the specific case, how do i make it so that it detects upper and lowercase?

```
String str = oIn.nextLine();
char ch = oIn.nextLine().charAt(0); 
int count = 0;
int index = str.indexOf(ch);

while (index >= 0){
    index = str.indexOf(ch, index+1);
    count++;          
    System.out.println ("The amount of the character " + ch + " in " + str +" are " +count);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()

Comment: `String str = oIn.nextLine().toUpperCase();` or `String str = oIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();`

Comment: turn the characters to lowercase with `Character.toLowerCase` and compare or use `String::toLowerCase` and compare them for strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn the character being compared against to lowercase with [`Character.toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-) prior to comparison.

i.e. change this:

```
char ch = oIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

to this:

```
char ch = Character.toLowerCase(oIn.nextLine().charAt(0));
```

Then call lowercase on this string:

```
String str = oIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

Now you're ready to utilise `String#indexOf` to find the index of the character with case ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = oIn.nextLine().toLowerCase();
char ch = Character.toLowerCase(oIn.nextLine().charAt(0));
int count = 0;        
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
   if(str.charAt(i) == ch ){
      count++;
   }
}
System.out.println ("The frequency of the character " + ch + " in " + str +" is " +count);
```